# Call startActivity(intent) Multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello at the moment I have a problem with calling a new activity.

I want to call a new Activity Inside my SettingsActivity.

I call the SettingsActivity by pressing an Button :

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_navSecond);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivityModern.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

But at the next Button click to get to another Acitivty inside this Activity I get back to the Mainactivity

```
premiumBuy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                               
    @Override                                                                                            
    public void onClick(View view) {                                                                     
        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivityModern.this, BuyPremiumActivity.class);               
        startActivity(intent);                                                                           
    }                                                                                                    
});
```

It seems like it is not possible to Call `startActivity(intent);` inside an activty which was called with this command. So how to prevent that?

Comment: Is there any log in logcat and manifest.xml ?

Comment: @UpendraShah ahhh I forgot to declare the Activity in the AndroidManifest......

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.foodgent.YOUR_ACTIVITY" />
```

Comment: This was my mistake